# i create a table but i got error in inserting the values in it

Tags: java, mysql

I created a table, but I got an error in inserting the values in it.here while doing insertion a[] is the string array which I passed to the function. I got the following error:

`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Here's my code:

```
 try
        {
            String tablename=c+d;
            String ab="";

              for(int i=1 ; i<=k ; i++)
              {
                   ab =ab+"column"+i+" VARCHAR(255),";
              }
            //establish connection to database

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","rohma");
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            //resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT idactors,firstname,lastname FROM actors");

              String sql ="CREATE TABLE  "  + tablename + "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "  + ab + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
              statement.executeUpdate(sql);

              int ki=0;
              //
              String abv ="";
              String tv="";
              int gk =1;
              for(int i =0 ; i<k ;i++)
              {    
                   // colum shows i and j shows fieds insertion  
                  for(int j=0 ; j<p ; j++)
                  { 
                    if(j<p-1)
                    {
                    abv =abv +"'"+a[ki]+"'"+"," ; 
                    ki++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        abv =abv +"'"+a[ki]+"'"; 
                        ki++;
                    }
                  }
                  tv ="INSERT INTO `abc`.`"+tablename+"` (`column "+gk+"`) VALUES ("+abv+")";
                  gk++;
                  statement.executeUpdate(tv);
              }

        }
```

Comment: `(\`column "+gk+"\`) VALUES ("+abv+")";` you have no `column 1` field in your table. you have just `id` column

Comment: even then you declared `"column"+i+" VARCHAR(255),"` with no space, but when insert you have space there: `(\`column "+gk+"\`)`

Comment: ok i have changed the code kindly see below my answer to this post,but it still gives error

Answer (score 3):

You create the column name with:

```
ab =ab+"column"+i+" VARCHAR(255),";
```

But when you do the insert there is a space after the word column in your code:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`"+tablename+"` (`column "+gk+"`)
```

It should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`"+tablename+"` (`column"+gk+"`)
```

You can add a print out when creating the table and before executing the SQL to make sure the amount of columns is the same as the amount of insert VALUES. Also to make sure the column in the insert is the same as the one created.

Answer (score 1):

When create table you do :

```
for(int i=1 ; i<=k ; i++) {
   ab =ab+"column"+i+" VARCHAR(255),";
}
```

but when you prepare for insert you do:

```
for(int i =0 ; i<k ;i++) {   
...
 ded = ded+"`column"+gk+"`,";
...
}
```

so your problem is different indexes used for column names.

try to:

```
for(int i =1 ; i<=k ;i++) {   
...
 ded = ded+"`column"+i+"`,";
...
}
```